# Add number to each result of foreach

Tags: php, foreach

How can I echo each result with a number ?
First result will be 1 etc.

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
echo "{Number: '"THE_NUMBERRR"', period:'".date('j F, Y',strtotime($result->getDate()))."', Visites: ".$result->getVisitors()."},\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$i = 0;
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{   
    echo "{Number: '".(++$i)."', period:'".date('j F, Y',strtotime($result->getDate()))."', Visites: ".$result->getVisitors()."},\n";
}
```